# Android HTML.fromHTML() with images?

Tags: java, android

My Android application receives HTML content with images in it. Is it possible to make `fromHTML()` function to display the images in the HTML String it receives?

If not, how can I retrieve the images in the `HTML` string and convert them to TextView images?

Thanks

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/55644885/2695282 check that out

Comment: For a modern approach using Kotlin and coroutines + Glide see: https://stackoverflow.com/a/58091529/683658

Answer (score 57, accepted):

**URLDrawable.java**

```
public class URLDrawable extends BitmapDrawable {
    // the drawable that you need to set, you could set the initial drawing
    // with the loading image if you need to
    protected Drawable drawable;

    @Override
    public void draw(Canvas canvas) {
        // override the draw to facilitate refresh function later
        if(drawable != null) {
            drawable.draw(canvas);
        }
    }
}
```

**URLImageParser.java**

```
public class URLImageParser implements ImageGetter {
    Context c;
    View container;

    /***
     * Construct the URLImageParser which will execute AsyncTask and refresh the container
     * @param t
     * @param c
     */
    public URLImageParser(View t, Context c) {
        this.c = c;
        this.container = t;
    }

    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        URLDrawable urlDrawable = new URLDrawable();

        // get the actual source
        ImageGetterAsyncTask asyncTask = 
            new ImageGetterAsyncTask( urlDrawable);

        asyncTask.execute(source);

        // return reference to URLDrawable where I will change with actual image from
        // the src tag
        return urlDrawable;
    }

    public class ImageGetterAsyncTask extends AsyncTask<String, Void, Drawable>  {
        URLDrawable urlDrawable;

        public ImageGetterAsyncTask(URLDrawable d) {
            this.urlDrawable = d;
        }

        @Override
        protected Drawable doInBackground(String... params) {
            String source = params[0];
            return fetchDrawable(source);
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Drawable result) {
            // set the correct bound according to the result from HTTP call
            urlDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + result.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0 
                    + result.getIntrinsicHeight()); 

            // change the reference of the current drawable to the result
            // from the HTTP call
            urlDrawable.drawable = result;

            // redraw the image by invalidating the container
            URLImageParser.this.container.invalidate();
        }

        /***
         * Get the Drawable from URL
         * @param urlString
         * @return
         */
        public Drawable fetchDrawable(String urlString) {
            try {
                InputStream is = fetch(urlString);
                Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
                drawable.setBounds(0, 0, 0 + drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), 0 
                        + drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()); 
                return drawable;
            } catch (Exception e) {
                return null;
            } 
        }

        private InputStream fetch(String urlString) throws MalformedURLException, IOException {
            DefaultHttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
            HttpGet request = new HttpGet(urlString);
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(request);
            return response.getEntity().getContent();
        }
    }
}
```

**Usage of ImageGetter**

```
String html = "Hello " +
"<img src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/" + 
"f9dd8b16d54f483f22c0b7a7e3d840f9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG'/>" +
" This is a test " +
"<img src='http://www.gravatar.com/avatar/a9317e7f0a78bb10a980cadd9dd035c9?s=32&d=identicon&r=PG'/>";

this.textView = (TextView)this.findViewById(R.id.textview);
URLImageParser p = new URLImageParser(textView, this);
Spanned htmlSpan = Html.fromHtml(html, p, null);
textView.setText(htmlSpan);
```

Comment: What if the image is Base64 String?

Comment: Didn't quite work for me but upvoted for the approach but others having problem with this answer may have a look here as it works for me! https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179285/html-imagegetter-textview/16209680#16209680

Comment: is there a way to set the  size of ther image in the html tag because i think this code tries to put the image in the original size. And width="" doesn´t work

Comment: omfg WHY U USING library http

Comment: Note: Kindly call container.setText(container.getText()); at the end of onPostExecute  to avoid overlapping of images ( if multiple images) and overlapping of image and text . To do so we have to keep container as TextView instead of just View

Comment: I got stuck with the issue ::: The inline style not applied , like style=color:red;"

Answer (score 0):

Note : Kindly refer the answer given by Talha , I am posting this as separate answer to point out important fix for an issue .

Fix for overlapping of images (if multiple images ) issue and fix for overlapping of image and text

Solution for above issues: 
Kindly call **container.setText(container.getText());** at the end of **onPostExecute** to avoid overlapping of images.