# Android - How to set button different value than its string?

Tags: android, button, textview

I have buttons that write into a textview. I want to write "?", but it's not allowed in strings.xml. So, I want the button to have different value (which is written to the textview) than the text in the button. How can I do this? Thanks in advance.

Comment: what do you want to do?

Comment: I want to write "?" to a textview with a button.

Comment: did you already wrote some code? Would you like to share it ?

Comment: ? is allowed in strings.xml

Comment: No it says "error: Error: Resource id cannot be an empty string (at 'buttonq' with value '?')."

Comment: @KitAndKat : not in first position, as it is interpreted as designing an id  `?string/bla`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use

```
<string name="question">\?</string>
```

to escape the question mark.

Comment: Thanks, it works. And how can I write a space whit another button?

Answer (score 0):

Also , you can try Html.fromHtml programmatically.
Following link discusses that.
[android-TextView setText in Html.fromHtml to display image and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396462/android-textview-settext-in-html-fromhtml-to-display-image-and-text)

Thanks 
JRH