# TextView with Html + <img base64/>

Tags: android, html, image, textview

I would like to display images (png, gif) stored in a string that has the html tag ( , < im /> ...).
Show Html no problem, but the images aren't working.
I saw examples on the Internet but only for a string that contains only ONE image without text and more.

```
description.setText(Html.fromHtml(new.getDescription()));
```

Example:

```html
"<p>Text before image</p>\r\n<p><img style="max-width: 100%;" src="data:image/gif;base64,R0lGODlhMgA2APQAACgoKDg4ODiQaFCQEHi4IEDYcGiIuIhYKLhoIMAYIPh/></p>"
```

Thx all for answers.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

In short, to make this happen, you need use the expanded overload of Html.fromHtml:

```
description.setText(Html.fromHtml(new.getDescription(), new CustomImageGetter(), null));
```

And you have to create the CustomImageGetter itself (it implements ImageGetter), and make CustomImageGetter.getDrawable return a drawable constructed from your byte string. It might be easier to do a WebView, or to save the byte string as a resource and use the CustomImageGetter to get that instead.

This question is similar to another stack overflow question: [android-TextView setText in Html.fromHtml to display image and text](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16396462/android-textview-settext-in-html-fromhtml-to-display-image-and-text), which can help you set up a CustomImageGetter that will return a drawable from a resource. Then you can start playing around with getting the byte string to work.