# View HTML code using Html.fromHtml() doesn't get image - Android

Tags: android, html, web-services, textview

I'm developing a News App.
Webservice returns me a String of HTML code. It is the content of an Article :

```
String result;
// result is returned from Webservice
result = "<p>Simply put, the 2013 Billboard Music Awards included a sizable helping of Bieber, with two performances in three hours and a Top Male Artist win before the Milestone Award was presented. Three months after another Justin -- Mr. Timberlake -- kept popping up at the 2013 Grammys and threatened overexposure, perhaps the audience at the Billboard Music Awards simply tired of seeing Bieber show up on stage and snag more of the spotlight.<br/><img align=\"Middle\" alt=\"\" border=\"0\" class=\"oImage\" height=\"335\" src=\"http://img2.news.zing.vn/2013/05/22/u2.jpg\" width=\"500\" \\/><br/>Plus, in the middle of the perceived mayhem was a monster-selling tour, with tons of Beliebers blissfully taking in the spectacle. But a dark cloud seemed embedded within the scraps of news coming from Bieber's tour over the past few months, and the Billboard Music Award boos could have been festering ill will toward one, some or all of them.<br/><img align=\"Middle\" alt=\"\" border=\"0\" class=\"oImage\" height=\"289\" src=\"http://img2.news.zing.vn/2013/05/22/u1.jpg\" width=\"500\"/></p>";
```

As you see, there are 2 image urls inside "result". "result" is the content of whole article.

When i use TextView to view the content of this article, images don't display :

```
TextView content = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvContent);
content.setText(Html.fromHtml(result));
```

How can i display content of this article fit the screen and all images are display.
Here is [my code](http://www.mediafire.com/download/kalshvow8g3g0if/NewsDemo.zip).

Thank for helping.

Comment: see this thread http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179285/html-imagegetter-textview

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need a Webview for this.Not textview. Here is how it can be implemented.

```
    Description = (WebView)findViewById(R.id.webView1);
        Description.getSettings().setLayoutAlgorithm(LayoutAlgorithm.SINGLE_COLUMN);
        WebSettings webSettings = Description.getSettings();
        webSettings.setTextSize(WebSettings.TextSize.NORMAL);
Description.loadDataWithBaseURL (null, "<html><p>Simply put, the 2013 Billboard Music Awards included a sizable helping of Bieber, with two performances in three hours and a Top Male Artist win before the Milestone Award was presented. Three months after another Justin -- Mr. Timberlake -- kept popping up at the 2013 Grammys and threatened overexposure, perhaps the audience at the Billboard Music Awards simply tired of seeing Bieber show up on stage and snag more of the spotlight.<br/><img align=\"Middle\" alt=\"\" border=\"0\" class=\"oImage\" height=\"335\" src=\"http://img2.news.zing.vn/2013/05/22/u2.jpg\" width=\"500\" \\/><br/>Plus, in the middle of the perceived mayhem was a monster-selling tour, with tons of Beliebers blissfully taking in the spectacle. But a dark cloud seemed embedded within the scraps of news coming from Bieber's tour over the past few months, and the Billboard Music Award boos could have been festering ill will toward one, some or all of them.<br/><img align=\"Middle\" alt=\"\" border=\"0\" class=\"oImage\" height=\"289\" src=\"http://img2.news.zing.vn/2013/05/22/u1.jpg\" width=\"500\"/></p></html>", "text/html", "UTF-8",null);
```

And your layout,

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" >
            <WebView
                android:id="@+id/webView1"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent" />

   </RelativeLayout>
```