# Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException Android

Tags: android, html, image

I was trying to get HTML content from a website and displaying it in a Text View. But i am getting an error:

```
"Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException"
```

This is the logcat:

```
03-10 10:41:22.905: E/BitmapFactory(2994): Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /http:/www.mobileappscentre.co.uk/healthapp/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/tmt-instability-226x300.jpg: open failed: ENOENT (No such file or directory)
```

This is my code used for

```
Spanned htmlSpan = Html.fromHtml(display, new ImageGetter() {           
    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {

      String path =  source;    

      Drawable bmp = Drawable.createFromPath(path);
      bmp.setBounds(0, 0, bmp.getIntrinsicWidth(), bmp.getIntrinsicHeight());

      Drawable bmp = null;
      return bmp;
    }
}, null);
blog.setText(htmlSpan);
```

When I Toast the file 'path' , I am getting correct URL.

Comment: Cross check your http `URL`

Comment: I already checked it. I Toasted the String 'path'and I am getting current URL. But in log cat the URL is "/http:/www.mobileappscentre.co.uk/healthapp/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/tmt-instability-226x300.jpg"

Comment: Not the path , check the URL you are using in browser , is it available or not.

Comment: or kindly look at this post: [/html-imagegetter-textview](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179285/html-imagegetter-textview?rq=1)

Comment: '/http:/www.mobileappscentre.co.uk/healthapp/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/tmt-inst‌​ability-226x300.jpg' this is the log cat URL. It is not found. But the URL i got when i toast is "http://www.mobileappscentre.co.uk/healthapp/wp-content/uploads/2013/11/tmt-inst‌​ability-226x300.jpg" that url has an image

Comment: Thanks Simple Plan, Let me try that solution

Comment: @Simple plan, that link Helped me, Thanks

Comment: @Arun now, your issue solved.that was great.