# Display images in between TextView

Tags: android

In string.xml, I have one string array having multiple items.

```
< string-array name="content">
< item>
< ![CDATA[text line 1
testing testing testing
testing testing testing]]>
< /item>
```

I am displaying this item in a TextView inside a fragment using below code:

```
String content = getResources().getStringArray(R.array.content)[i];
text = (TextView)rootView.findViewById(R.id.textView1);
text.setText(Html.fromHtml(content));
```

Now, I want to insert images in between this text. For example one image after "text line 1" and another image after "testing testing".
How can I achieve this functionality ?

--Sushant

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can achieve same task with the help of ImageGetter class.
try below code:-

```
public class TestImageGetter extends Activity implements ImageGetter {
    private final static String TAG = "TestImageGetter";
    private TextView mTv;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.test_image_getter);
        String source = "this is a test of <b>ImageGetter</b> it contains " +
                "two images: <br/>" +
                "<img src=\"http://developer.android.com/assets/images/dac_logo.png\"><br/>and<br/>" +
                "<img src=\"http://developer.android.com/assets/images/icon_search.png\">";

        Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml(source, this, null);
        mTv = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text);
        mTv.setText(spanned);
    }

    @Override
    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
        LevelListDrawable d = new LevelListDrawable();
        Drawable empty = getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.ic_launcher);
        d.addLevel(0, 0, empty);
        d.setBounds(0, 0, empty.getIntrinsicWidth(), empty.getIntrinsicHeight());

        new LoadImage().execute(source, d);

        return d;
    }

    class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<Object, Void, Bitmap> {

        private LevelListDrawable mDrawable;

        @Override
        protected Bitmap doInBackground(Object... params) {
            String source = (String) params[0];
            mDrawable = (LevelListDrawable) params[1];
            Log.d(TAG, "doInBackground " + source);
            try {
                InputStream is = new URL(source).openStream();
                return BitmapFactory.decodeStream(is);
            } catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            } catch (IOException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap bitmap) {
            Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute drawable " + mDrawable);
            Log.d(TAG, "onPostExecute bitmap " + bitmap);
            if (bitmap != null) {
                BitmapDrawable d = new BitmapDrawable(bitmap);
                mDrawable.addLevel(1, 1, d);
                mDrawable.setBounds(0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight());
                mDrawable.setLevel(1);
                // i don't know yet a better way to refresh TextView
                // mTv.invalidate() doesn't work as expected
                CharSequence t = mTv.getText();
                mTv.setText(t);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

see below link and i can achieve same task from help of below link :-

[Html.ImageGetter TextView](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16179285/html-imagegetter-textview)

Comment: Is there any way to handle this functionality in Strings.xml file ?