# How to make compoundView

Tags: android, html, textview

I have a scenario where I have a `String` which has `HTML` tag in it. In `html` tag,there can be many or one `img` tag.Now I have to show images embedded in text. For that I was using textview and I followed this great [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16209680/5275639). But it isn't giving me required result. So, then I searched on web & came across `CompoundView`

**Note** Restricted to want to use webview.

I have looked into these tutorials.

1. [tutplus](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/creating-compound-views-on-android--cms-22889)
2. [vogella](http://www.vogella.com/tutorials/AndroidCustomViews/article.html#views_androiddefaults)
3. Ryanharter's blog [post](http://ryanharter.com/blog/2014/05/14/using-custom-compound-views-in-android/)

But I am not getting much from where to start and how to start with. Since I have no idea how many image tag would be there in string.

It would be very nice if anyone of you guide me how to do it. Some guidelines would be much appreciated.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: if it is html content you want to show then use [WebView](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html)

Comment: I dont want to use webview

Comment: what do you mean by `"i dont want"`? this is the view which is used for that, do you want to write it by yourself?

Comment: I am assigned to displayed all html string in android app. Not in webview cuz webview mess up. Restricted to use webview. webview doesn't match with design perceptive.

Comment: what does it "mess up"? did you try it?

Comment: I have tired that. I doesn't go with design of UI and it takes some time to load data.

Comment: so write your own html renderer, it will take you one year if you find ten guys who will help you in that task, btw any page that you show using WebView can be customized as much as you want...

Comment: I will do it myself. Thanks for motivation.

Comment: Yes thanks i did it somehow see my answer below. You can let me know for improvements

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So after some hours of digging i found some solution here is the code with some details.

This answer may help someone. I used Jsoup to extract `<Img/>` tag out of the  string then i show the image in `ImageView` and `<p>` in `Textview`. Results was according to what i needed. Also i used Universal Image Loader Libaray to load images in `ImageView` Then i added view programmatically to the layout in my case layout was the linearlayout so i made a helper class and passed content,html string and linear layout as the parameter.

add jsoup in your project.

```
compile 'org.jsoup:jsoup:1.9.2'
```

Here some snippet.

```
public class PostContentHandler {
Context context;
String content;
LinearLayout linearLayout;

public PostContentHandler(Context context, String content, LinearLayout linearLayout) {
    this.context = context;
    this.content = content;
    this.linearLayout = linearLayout;

}

public void setContentToView() {

    //custom font
    Typeface bitterBoldFont = Typeface.createFromAsset(context.getAssets(), "fonts/Bitter-Regular.otf");

    List<String> p = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> src = new ArrayList<>();
    List<String> li = new ArrayList<>();
    Document doc = Jsoup.parse(content);

    Elements elements = doc.getAllElements();

    for (Element element : elements) {
        Tag tag = element.tag();
        if (tag.getName().matches("h[1-6]{1}")) {
            String heading = element.select(tag.getName().toString()).text();
            TextView textView = new TextView(context);
            textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
            int top = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.heading_margin_top);
            int start = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.content_margin);
            int end = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.content_margin);
            params.setMargins(start, top, end, 0);
            textView.setTextSize(20);
            textView.setTypeface(bitterBoldFont);
            textView.setText(heading);
            textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.black));
            linearLayout.addView(textView);
        }
 if (tag.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("p")) {
            element.select("img").remove();
            String body = element.html();
            TextView textView = new TextView(context);
            textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
            int top = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.heading_margin_top);
            int start = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.content_margin);
            int end = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.content_margin);
            params.setMargins(start, top, end, 0);
            textView.setTypeface(bitterBoldFont);
            textView.setLinksClickable(true);
            textView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(body));
            textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.content_color));
            linearLayout.addView(textView);
            p.add(body);
        }
        if (tag.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ol")) {
            String ol = element.select(tag.getName().toString()).outerHtml();
            TextView textView = new TextView(context);
            textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
            params.setMarginStart((int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.content_margin));
            int top = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.heading_margin_top);
            int start = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.content_margin);
            int end = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.content_margin);
            params.setMargins(start, top, end, 0);
            textView.setTypeface(bitterBoldFont);
            textView.setLinksClickable(true);
            textView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
            textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.content_color));
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(ol, null, new MyTagHandler()));
            linearLayout.addView(textView);

        }
        if (tag.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("ul")) {
            String ul = element.select(tag.getName().toString()).outerHtml();
            TextView textView = new TextView(context);

            textView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            LinearLayout.LayoutParams params = (LinearLayout.LayoutParams) textView.getLayoutParams();
            int top = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.heading_margin_top);
            int start = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.content_margin);
            int end = (int) context.getResources().getDimension(R.dimen.content_margin);
            params.setMargins(start, top, end, 0);
            textView.setTypeface(bitterBoldFont);
            textView.setLinksClickable(true);
            textView.setAutoLinkMask(Linkify.WEB_URLS);
            textView.setTextColor(context.getResources().getColor(R.color.content_color));
            textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(ul, null, new MyTagHandler()));
            linearLayout.addView(textView);
        }
        if (tag.getName().equalsIgnoreCase("img")) {
            String url = element.select("img").attr("src");
            final ImageView imageView = new ImageView(context);
            imageView.setLayoutParams(new LinearLayout.LayoutParams(LinearLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
                    LinearLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
            final ProgressBar progressBar = new ProgressBar(context);
            linearLayout.addView(progressBar);
            progressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            ImageLoader imageLoader = ImageLoader.getInstance();
            imageLoader.displayImage(url, imageView, new SimpleImageLoadingListener() {
                @Override
                public void onLoadingComplete(String imageUri, View view, Bitmap loadedImage) {
                    super.onLoadingComplete(imageUri, view, loadedImage);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                    int height = loadedImage.getHeight();
                    imageView.getLayoutParams().height = getScreenWidth();
                    imageView.setAdjustViewBounds(true);
                    imageView.requestLayout();
                }

                @Override
                public void onLoadingStarted(String imageUri, View view) {
                    super.onLoadingStarted(imageUri, view);
                    progressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                }
            });
            linearLayout.addView(imageView);
            src.add(url);
        }

    }
}

public static int getScreenWidth() {
    return Resources.getSystem().getDisplayMetrics().widthPixels;
}
}
```

I hope my answer will help someone.