# read html object in textview on android studio

Tags: java, android, android-studio

So i want that is possible to see things in html like 50% and not just text or link also if it's possible that it's shows pictures. i think you see what i want to do that with the same html code than for a webpage it shows the same things.

this is my code

```
TextView tv = (TextView) findViewById( R.id.textView4 );
tv.setMovementMethod( LinkMovementMethod.getInstance() );
tv.setText( Html.fromHtml( String.valueOf( str ) )  );
```

thanks for helping i didn't see something on the net that helped me.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to implement `Html.ImageGetter` in your class that is processing the HTML. Then you will need to override `getDrawable()` which gets triggered when `Html.fromHtml()` encounters a `src` attribute in the html. You can read more about it here:

[From the Android docs on `getDrawable()`:](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.ImageGetter)

> This method is called when the HTML parser encounters an  tag. The source argument is the string from the "src" attribute; the return value should be a Drawable representation of the image or null for a generic replacement image. Make sure you call setBounds() on your Drawable if it doesn't already have its bounds set.

[Example implementation with AsyncTask](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16209680/3851567)

Important part is to use an AsyncTask or an IntentService to download the images on a separate thread.

Answer (score -2):

If you want to display something in textview like html format then you try to:

tv.setText( Html.fromHtml("

### Title

Description here

"));

https://stackoverflow.com/a/2116191/6804857

Comment: It's already the case but i can't display picture or a balise `<meter value="0.50">50%</meter>`

Comment: so you are trying to display image in textview using html?