# Images in TextView Android

Tags: android, textview

May be this Question has been asked earlier but i did not found any appropriate answer. My question is i have text View inside text i have some image resources.
e.g.

```
http://xyz.abc.in/sites/xyz.abc.in/icons/wifi.jpg "SomeText goes here
http://xyz.abc.in/sites/xyz.abc.in/icons/lcd.jpg "Somtext goes here"
http://xyz.abc.in/sites/xyz.abc.in/icons/storage.jpg "SomeText goes here"
```

Now I want to put one of those images to the left side of the text(like bullet points). How can I do this? The images are coming from the server and can be changed.

Response :

```
<div class=\"specsSection\">\n<p><strong>Entertainment on the Go</strong></p>\n
 <table cellpadding=\"5\" cellspacing=\"0\" border=\"0\" class=\"tblSpecs\"><tr><td>
<img src=\"http://xyz.abc.in/sites/xyz.abc.in/icons/dolbyplus.jpg\" />
</td>\n<td>Sharp and Natural Sound with Digital Dolby Plus</td>\n</tr><tr><td>
<img src=\"http://xyz.abc.in/sites/xyz.abc.in/icons/wifi.jpg\" /></td>\n<td>
 GPRS + WiFi (With Voice Calling)</td>\n</tr><tr><td>
<img src=\"http://xyz.abc.in/sites/xyz.abc.in/icons/lcd.jpg\" /></td>\n
<td>7\"Capacitive Touch LCD</td>\n</tr><tr><td>
<img src=\"http://xyz.abc.in/sites/xyz.abc.in/icons/dualcore.jpg\" /></td>\n
<td>Dual Core Processor</td>\n</tr><tr><td>
<img src=\"http://xyz.abc.in/sites/xyz.abc.in/icons/storage.jpg\" /></td>\n
<td>1 GB RAM, 4 GB eMMC</td>\n</tr><tr><td>
<img src=\"http://xyz.abc.in/sites/xyz.abc.in/icons/android.jpg\" /></td>\n
<td>Andorid 4.2 JellyBean</td>\n</tr><tr><td>
<img src=\"http://xyz.abc.in/sites/xyz.abc.in/icons/battery.jpg\" /></td>\n
<td>7+ hours of battery life</td>\n</tr></table></div>\n<div style=\"clear:both\">   </div>\n",
```

Comment: Do you just want to display a web page?

Comment: getting both text and images and want to render as full html page. in the second fragment.

Comment: It is not clear what part of your activity need to show html. There is an option to create html page dynamically by getting text from server. Will you application will have native android UI or only HTML?

Comment: See i have two fragment form there i have 4 button on the basis of clicked button i am loading my data in second fragment. it can be full text or can be image and text or video too. Its only depends upon which button have you clicked.

Comment: Do you show the text/image/video as html or native android or you don't care?

Comment: native only.one more thing i want to use only one fragment to display all kind of data.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/43904/discussion-between-rup35h-and-babibu)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@Kirk idea is good. How ever it is not that simple to implement. If you are reading the description of [Html.fromHtml()](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/text/Html.html#fromHtml%28java.lang.String%29) it says:

> Returns displayable styled text from the provided HTML string. Any
>    tags in the HTML will display as a generic replacement image
>   which your program can then go through and replace with real images.

[Here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617210/android-html-fromhtml-with-images) is a good implementation of that idea.

Answer (score 0):

Try out below code to load the image form url

Implement the `Html.ImageGetter's` `getDrawable` method which handles downloading the image, or accessing it from the net, and then create a drawable and return that object.
?

```
static ImageGetter imgGetter = new Html.ImageGetter() {
        @Override
       public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
           Drawable drawable = null;
           drawable = Drawable.createFromPath(source);  // Or fetch it from the URL
           // Important
           drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable
.getIntrinsicHeight());
           return drawable;
    }
    };
```

and use the method on the TextView like this.?

```
  tv.setText(Html.fromHtml(source, imgGetter, null);
```

Comment: Again i am getting the image url from the server that can be change.Just one i wanted to know how i put the image like html.

Comment: its like in place of bullet point i want to pit image e.g. 
<wi-fi iamge> 3g+Wifi
<android image> 4.0
I know how to store image in bitmap form url

Comment: how to stores html tags and text separately from response.
Currently i am storing only text filtering all tag.
By using this replaceAll("\\<.*?>", "") . now i want to store only this tag <img src=\"http://xyz.abc.in/sites/xyz.abc.in/icons/lcd.jpg\ also

Answer (score 0):

**One simple way is this.**

```
int imageNumber = 1;

String textLine = "<html><body><b>Test</b><i>Italic</i><br/>"
        + "<img src=\"dial.png\"/>This is sample " + "<img src=\"dial.png\"/>" +
                "</body></html>";
textView.setText(Html.fromHtml(textLine , imageGetter, null));

private ImageGetter imageGetter= new ImageGetter() {

    public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
            Drawable drawable = null;
            if(imageNumber == 1) {
            drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.raw.icon);
            ++imageNumber;
            } else drawable = getResources().getDrawable(R.raw.a);
            drawable.setBounds(0, 0, drawable.getIntrinsicWidth(), drawable
                                .getIntrinsicHeight());

            return drawable;
    }
};
```

**or if you want to do it by using XML, try this**

```
<TextView
    android:id="@+id/textImage"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="center"
    android:drawableLeft="@drawable/dial"
    android:drawablePadding="4dp"
    android:singleLine="true"
    android:text="@string/textName"/>
```

**Edited:**

I found this code somewhere on this forum: it parse HTML like XML Parser
use this small [lib](http://jsoup.org/)

```
File input = new File("/tmp/input.html");
Document doc = Jsoup.parse(input, "UTF-8", "http://example.com/");

Element content = doc.getElementById("content");
Elements links = content.getElementsByTag("a");
for (Element link : links) {
   String linkHref = link.attr("href");
   String linkText = link.text();
}
```

honestly i didn't test above code. code standard much likely to handle like xml tags. so readi it by "ID" or "scr"

just give it a try!

Comment: Looks like helpful let me check once.Any way thanks for answering.

Comment: how to stores html tags and text separately from response.
Currently i am storing only text filtering all tag.
By using this replaceAll("\\<.*?>", "") . now i want to store only this tag <img src=\"http://xyz.abc.in/sites/xyz.abc.in/icons/lcd.jpg\ also

Comment: which response you mean?

Comment: Still u can replace dial.png by your huge url. dnt use replace for this link?

Comment: Image url and text in same response.i will have to categories then only i can use this.

Comment: Let me find some solution for that

Comment: getDrawable(String source) { here source is image file source or full response??

Answer (score 0):

Easiest way to do this:

```
SpannableStringBuilder builder = new SpannableStringBuilder();


builder.setSpan(new ImageSpan(getApplicationContext(),getImageFromWeb(imglink)),0, builder.length(),
                Spannable.SPAN_EXCLUSIVE_EXCLUSIVE);
textview.setText(builder);
```

to get  image from server:

```
public static Bitmap getImageFromWeb(String imglink) throws IOException
{

Bitmap bmpImage;

URL imgURL = new URL(imglink.toString());
URLConnection conn = imgURL.openConnection();
conn.setConnectTimeout(7000);
conn.connect();

InputStream is = conn.getInputStream();
BufferedInputStream bis = new BufferedInputStream(is);

bmpImage = BitmapFactory.decodeStream(bis);
bis.close();
is.close();
return bmpImage;

}
```