# Android Java: Several ImageParser from html string

Tags: java, android, html, json

I want to display the content of news with Json. I tried to do `Html.fromHTML()` to display the style (bold, italic etc).
Then, I want to display image from html img in my textView.

I tried [this image parser](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617210/android-html-fromhtml-with-images) but this work only for the first image and the image pass over the text.

I need help for parse image from HTML or from json before `Html.fromHTML()`

This is my code: (without ImagePaser, this is in the link above)

```
  URLImageParser p = new URLImageParser(description_projet, this);
  Spanned htmlSpan = Html.fromHtml(json_data.getString("contenu"), p, null);
  description_projet.setText(htmlSpan);
```

Thanks