# Online images in local Webview page in Android

Tags: android, html, webview

I have a webview showing a local html page resource in a string like this:

```html
<p>Hi.</p>

<p><img alt="" src="http://ADRESS.COM/image.jpg" style="height:300px; width:400px" /></p>
```

and doing that with this code:

```
    WebView web = (WebView) findViewById(R.id.web);
    web.getSettings().setJavaScriptEnabled(true);
    web.loadDataWithBaseURL("",notice,"text/html","UTF-8","");
```

The page contains some images with online src. but in android WebView the images doesn't load. (in chrome it works).
What I should do?

thanks.

Comment: Check [this Answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/15617341/2999385), may help you.

Comment: Have you added `INTERNET` permission in the manifest?

Comment: Yes @KNeerajLal

Comment: Code seems fine. Are there any issues with showing the image in the phones browser?

Comment: The page is just a string html source. how can i open it in phone browser? @KNeerajLal

Comment: No, but you can open the image.

Comment: I checked it as a html file in chrome and it worked (Loaded images). but i think that there is some settings for webview to load images also in webview. @KNeerajLal

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add these two lines in your code.

```
web.getSettings().setLoadsImagesAutomatically(true);
web.getSettings().setDomStorageEnabled(true);
```

Instead of using `web.loadDataWithBaseURL("",notice,"text/html","UTF-8","");` simply load your website url as follows

```
web.loadUrl("http://www.google.com");
```

if you want load your local html page. Create **asset** directory android then put your html file in **asset** folder and and set it as follows

```
web.loadUrl("file:///android_asset/yourFile.html");
```

Comment: still doesn't load images.

Comment: because you are loading webpage html with text format

Comment: I edited the answer @SaeedKetabi please check it . If it works for you then don not forget to up vote. Thank you

Comment: But i don't want load any site. i load just a html local page source. @SaurabhBhandari

Comment: @SaeedKetabi now check my answer. if you dont how to create asset folder then follow this link http://code2care.org/2015/create-assets-folder-in-android-studio/

Comment: But i should to create a html file in asset folder when app is runnig. becuase i get the html file resource online in a string.

Comment: I get a html file source containing text and image from server and now i want to load it into my Activity. Images are uploaded on server and now Webview doesn't load images.

Comment: @SaeedKetabi webView loads web pages not a particular part of a web page. if your webpage working in your laptop or PC browser then it will run in your app.