# Is it possible to Display a image from url in HTML tag in Android TextView through Html.fromHtml()

Tags: android, html, image, textview

Here is the code,
I want the image to be displayed.I also tried Size with it.

```
TextView textViewHtml = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.text_html_program);
        Spanned spanned = Html.fromHtml( "<b>text_html_program: Constructed from HTML programmatically.</b>"
                + "  Text with a <a href=\"http://www.google.com\">link</a> "
                +"<b><img src=\"http://innovativeprofessionaloffices.com/wp-content/uploads/2014/07/seo-for-small-business.jpg\" alt=\"testing\"></b>"
                + "created in the Java source code using HTML.");
        textViewHtml.setText(spanned);
        textViewHtml.setMovementMethod(LinkMovementMethod.getInstance());
```

Comment: Refer below link - http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15617210/android-html-fromhtml-with-images/15617341#15617341

Comment: @Ragini Thank helped a lot but TextView refresh isn't working I guess.Showed me once only.

Answer (score 0):

you can get the img tag using following pattern as below:

```
    String ptr= "src\\s*=\\s*([\"'])?([^\"']*)";
        Pattern p = Pattern.compile(ptr);
        Matcher m;
//find the img tag

  m = p.matcher(html_string_containg_img_Tag);
        if (m.find()) {
           m.group(2),img);//this line get the image tag from give string
        }
```

may this helpful for you

Comment: I dont think this is the solution to Display image,Brother i want to display image int textview, that's my problem.

Comment: you can't display image in textView you have to use ImageView for it.

Comment: may be set but it'll help you to get img url from string. and than do whatever you want with url.