# Apply html tags to textview in android

Tags: android, html

I am displaying data from sqlite db. The data in the database is stored in html. The data contains an image tag to display an image. I am able to display the data but how can I display the image along with it? My images are stored in the server.

My Code:

```
((TextView)view.findViewById(R.id.tv_text)).setText(Html.fromHtml(listItem.gettext()+""));
```

From the above line I am displaying the data from database. Now along with that I need to display the image which is in server. How can I do this?

Comment: See here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2865452/is-it-possible-to-display-inline-images-from-html-in-an-android-textview

Comment: [Check this once](http://stackoverflow.com/a/1992955/940096)

Comment: http://blog.stylingandroid.com/archives/177#

Comment: hi thanks for the links..those links are helpful...But I have small doubt...in all those I found getting the image statically..how can I get the image dynamically? Because I am working on quiz app..so along with the question I need to display its related image...so here I cant give the image name statically...Please help me regarding this...

Answer (score 0):

Try my code . Hope it helps

```
TextView mDetail;
ProgressBar mProgressBar;
String body;
Handler handler;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.act_recipe_detail);
    getActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    if (this.getIntent().getStringExtra("body") != null)
        body = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("body");

    mDetail = (TextView) this.findViewById(R.id.tv_recipe_detail);

    if (this.getIntent().getStringExtra("body") != null)
        body = this.getIntent().getStringExtra("body");

    mDetail.setText(Html.fromHtml(body));

    mProgressBar = (ProgressBar) this.findViewById(R.id.bar);
    mDetail.setMovementMethod(ScrollingMovementMethod.getInstance());// 皛
    handler = new Handler() {
        @Override
        public void handleMessage(Message msg) {
            // TODO Auto-generated method stub
            if (msg.what == 0x101) {
                mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                mDetail.setText((CharSequence) msg.obj);
            }
            super.handleMessage(msg);
        }
    };
    Thread t = new Thread(new ImageTask());
    t.start();
    mProgressBar.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

}
class ImageTask implements Runnable {
    Message msg = Message.obtain();

    @Override
    public void run() {

        ImageGetter imageGetter = new ImageGetter() {
            @Override
            public Drawable getDrawable(String source) {
                // TODO Auto-generated method stub
                URL url;
                Drawable drawable = null;
                try {
                    url = new URL(source);
                    drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(
                            url.openStream(), null);

                    int scale_y = MAX_HEIGHT/drawable.getIntrinsicHeight();
                    drawable.setBounds(0, 0,
                            drawable.getIntrinsicWidth()*scale_y,
                            drawable.getIntrinsicHeight()*scale_y);

                } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "MalformedURLException" + e.toString());
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    Log.e(TAG, "IOException" + e.toString());
                }
                return drawable;
            }
        };
        CharSequence test = Html.fromHtml(body, imageGetter, null);
        msg.what = 0x101;
        msg.obj = test;
        handler.sendMessage(msg);
    }
}
```