# Parse html to display in android

Tags: android, html

I am getting this code from a service:

```
<p><a href="http://www.blabla.com><img class="myclass"…/></a></p>
```

Is that possible to convert this html code to see properly in android. I have seen that exists html encode but is the best way to do this? Thank You

Comment: Please explain in much more detail what "convert this html code to see properly" means.

Comment: Convert this code to see like in a web page, this I get from service and I want to display in a web view inside my app or parse and display in textview or image view...

Comment: What specific problems are you having? `WebView` can display HTML. `TextView` can display a `Spanned` object, and you can get one of those from HTML via `Html.fromHtml()`.

Comment: I have done like this myTextView.setText(Html.fromHtml("<p><a href="http://www.blabla.com><img class="myclass"…/></a></p>")); but the image has class and not display well

Comment: You can use my code
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10765870/apply-html-tags-to-textview-in-android/24109235#24109235

or using jsoup is cool, too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`TextView` cannot handle CSS, JavaScript, etc. You will need to use a `WebView` for more elaborate HTML like that.

Comment: Thanks, yes but the CSS and the javascript of the page is in the server, so if I display it in Webview too the styles can´t display well, isn´t it?

Comment: @Igor: If the HTML you load into the WebView has the proper URLs to the CSS and JavaScript, and your app has the `INTERNET` permission, it should work.

Comment: So I have to insert in my string <link rel='stylesheet' id='ci-style-css'  href='http://www.blabla.com/wp-content/themes/example.css?ver=1.4' type='text/css' media='screen' /> when I load the html code?

Comment: @Igor: The HTML you load into the `WebView` needs to be complete enough to render the way that you want. If you need that `<link>` to achieve this, then you will need to add it. One approach is to have a "template" HTML page, with all of the `<link>` and `<script>` and similar tags that you need. Then, at runtime, you pour the retrieved HTML into the template to generate the full Web page to be rendered.